# Is “Where IN” with multiple columns defined in Standard SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm working on a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM requests where (id,langid) IN (SELECT nid,langid FROM node)
```

My questions are

does this work in mysql and postgresql ?

is this something supported by Standard SQL ?

I know is not the best solution and a JOIN would work but I'm not interested in that.

Comment: Does not work in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Did you try with mysql and postgres?

Comment: it is. I just had the exactly same problems this day, and I really tried it and it worked :)

Answer (score 12):

Standard and portable SQL would be EXISTS.. and is semantically the same IN

```
SELECT *
FROM requests R
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM node n
           WHERE r.id = n.nid AND r.langid = n.langid
           )
```

The multi-column IN isn't portable to SQL Server or Sybase at least.

Other notes:

- A JOIN may require a DISTINCT and is not the same as IN or EXISTS.
- The final option is INTERSECT which is less commonly supported and works like IN/EXISTS
- IIRC some prehistoric MySQL versions (3.x?) didn't support the correlation for EXISTS

Answer (score 8):

I checked that with PostgreSQL and it works (it is [officially supported](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/features-sql-standard.html)), but it's your responsibility to make id ↔ nid and langid ↔ langid column types compatible (or use explicit casting).

I think it is pretty standard construct. I have [SQL:2003 draft](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip) and there is ***in predicate*** defined (as well as mentioned *exists predicate*).

**8.4 <in predicate>**

**Function**

Specify a quantified comparison.

**Format**

```
<in predicate> ::= <row value predicand> <in predicate part 2>
<in predicate part 2> ::= [ NOT ] IN <in predicate value>
<in predicate value> ::=
<table subquery>
| ... (rest is not important here)
```

**EDIT:**

As checked works well under MySQL too (version 5.0.90-log). [Here is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) documentation link.

Answer (score 7):

Your query would work in Postgres. Best I'm aware, not in MySQL.

The portable version for DBs that would support it is:

```
SELECT * FROM requests where ROW(id,langid) IN (SELECT nid,langid FROM node)
```

(`row` is a reserved keyword since [SQL:1999](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999).)

A more portable version will be to use `exists()` as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL code is valid as regards the SQL-92 Standard. You can confirm this for yourself using the [Mimer SQL-92 online validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml) ([SQL-99](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser99/index.tml) and [SQL:2003](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml) flavours also available). However, because it is a feature of Full SQL-92, it is not as widely implemented as perhaps it should be.

Relationally speaking, the operator in question is a [semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin), for which none of the SQL Standards (and none of the vendors' extensions?) has an explicit syntax.