# How to create a multi-column IN predicate with ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following 'distances' table:

```
╔════╦════════════╦════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║ origin_lat ║ origin_lng ║ destination_lat ║ destination_lng ║ distance ║
╠════╬════════════╬════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ 1.234567   ║ 2.345678   ║ 3.456789        ║ 4.567890        ║       10 ║
║  2 ║ 5.678901   ║ 6.789012   ║ 7.890123        ║ 8.901234        ║       20 ║
╚════╩════════════╩════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════╝
```

The question is, how can I create the following SQL query (supported by PostgreSQL) with ActiveRecord, and Arel, if necessary:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM distances
WHERE 
(origin_lat, origin_lng) IN ((1.234567, 2.345678), (5.678901, 6.789012))
AND
(destination_lat, destination_lng) IN ((3.456789, 4.567890), (7.890123, 8.901234));
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```ruby
Distance.where('(origin_lat, origin_lng) IN (?) AND (destination_lat, destination_lng) IN (?)', [[1.234567, 2.345678], [5.678901, 6.789012]], [[3.456789, 4.567890], [7.890123, 8.901234]])
```

It generates this:

```ruby
SELECT "distances".* FROM "distances"  WHERE ((origin_lat, origin_lng) IN ('---
- 1.234567
- 2.345678
','---
- 5.678901
- 6.789012
') AND (destination_lat, destination_lng) IN ('---
- 3.456789
- 4.56789
','---
- 7.890123
- 8.901234
'))
```

And raises `PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR:  input of anonymous composite types is not implemented`

The number of parameters is variable, so I can't just hard-code the query like this:

```ruby
Distance.where('(origin_lat, origin_lng) IN ((?,?),(?,?)) AND (destination_lat, destination_lng) IN ((?,?),(?,?))', 1.234567, 2.345678, 5.678901, 6.789012, 3.456789, 4.567890, 7.890123, 8.901234)
```

Am I going to need to drop to plain SQL? :/

Comment: Does the *raw* sql is a valid query ? Actually I never saw it before.

Comment: @ArupRakshit At least where I tested (MySQL and PostgreSQL), it is, and does exactly what I need.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I think it's even standard SQl, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298139/is-where-in-with-multiple-columns-defined-in-standard-sql and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672665/doing-a-where-in-on-multiple-columns-in-postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess my best shot is to build the "where SQL" string myself, flatten and splat the arguments, so I created this method:

```
class Distance < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.distance_matrix(origins, destinations)
    return false if origins.empty? || destinations.empty?

    where_sql =  '(origin_lat, origin_lng) IN ('
    where_sql << (['(?, ?)'] * origins.length).join(', ')
    where_sql << ') AND (destination_lat, destination_lng) IN ('
    where_sql << (['(?, ?)'] * destinations.length).join(', ') << ')'

    where(where_sql, *origins.flatten, *destinations.flatten)
  end
end
```

and call it like:

```
Distance.distance_matrix([[1.234567, 2.345678], [5.678901, 6.789012]], [[3.456789, 4.567890], [7.890123, 8.901234]])
```

And it works :D

Thanks to @BradWerth for getting me in the right track and to @muistooshort for making the code more readable.

Comment: You might want to use things like `['(?,?)'] * origins.length` as a possibly more readable version of `Array.new(origins.count, '(?, ?)')`. And if you use [postgres_ext](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext) with Rails3 you could simplify that to `['(?)'] * origins.length` and `*origins` in the argument list. I can't think of any other way to make AR behave sensibly but AR's understanding of SQL is so limited that I tend to go straight to doing it by hand at the drop of a hat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it has to be a little more like this:

Element.where('(origin_lat, origin_lng) IN ((?,?),(?,?)) AND (destination_lat, destination_lng) IN ((?,?),(?,?))', 1.234567, 2.345678, 5.678901, 6.789012, 3.456789, 4.567890, 7.890123, 8.901234)

Comment: This works, but the parameters (1.234567, 2.345678 etc), are not hard-coded, they come from arrays just like I posted. Gonna try to make this work, be right back.

Comment: Calling #flatten and splatting the outter array works. The problem is, the number of parameters is variable.

Comment: Well, the first parameter is really jsut a string, so you can construct it by iterating over your array and just tacking on as much as you need (if this makes sense)...

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is the best option. Thanks, gonna try it.