# Why can't I use tuples or ordered pairs in a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, tuples

Say I want to get the most recent row in a table that has a bunch of records with different IDs.

First, I create a temp table, where I find the most recent rows (grouped by ID of course):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
temp1
AS
SELECT DISTINCT ID, max(date) FROM atable GROUP BY ID;
```

But, since the whole point was to get all the values for these records, I have to join this back to the original table, `atable`. Annoying, but what can you do.

I really, really want to use a tuple or an order pair. Why can't I do this in MySQL??

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
WHERE (ID, date) IN 
      (SELECT ID, date FROM temp1);
```

What is the canonical syntax to do this?

(Further, philosophical question: Why is MySQL so clunky with this? It's been around decades, and nobody have ever implemented something this basic?)

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I do this in MySQL??

You can, but not with `IN`.  The way to match multiple columns is with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT NULL FROM temp1 
       WHERE temp1.ID = atable.ID AND temp1.date = atable.date);
```

Note that you could also use your original query as a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) FROM atable WHERE ID = atable.ID)
```

> Why is MySQL so clunky with this?

The "standard" use of `IN` is to find records where one value is contained in a list of other values (e.g. `WHERE NAME IN ('Smith', 'Jones')`.  This has been extended to allow a subquery to provide the list rather than a static list.

If you feel that it's a worthy feature for MySQL to implement (and you seem to think it's very easy) then you can submit a [feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/search.php), but since 1) there is another way to accomplish it and 2) it would be non-standard SQL I would be surprised if it got a lot of attention.

Comment: What is going on with `SELECT NULL FROM temp1`?

Comment: Is this the standard MySQL way?

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had 59 rows in temp1 and this query resulted in 229 rows.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck Yes this is the standard MySQL way - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6298265/1081897) as well.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck I'm assuming that `atable` contains multiple rows that meet that criteris.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck When you use [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) the values that you select are irrelevant, so `SELECT NULL` doesn;t really do anything.  You could just as well do `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95757/discussion-between-monica-heddneck-and-d-stanley).