# msyql compare values of two fields in subquery

Tags: mysql, select, union, where-in

I am using MySQL and have 3 tables like so:

```
Create Table users (
  firstName VARCHAR, 
  lastName VARCHAR, 
  userName VARCHAR, 
  email VARCHAR,
  created DATETIME, etc.

Create Table data_2013 (
  uid VARCHAR,
  d1 INT,
  d2 INT,
  d3 INT, etc

Create Table data_2016 (
  uid VARCHAR,
  d1 INT,
  d2 INT,
  d3 INT, etc
```

- The `uid` in the two data tables matches the `userName` field in the `users` table
- Each user is present in the `users` table twice (or more), but always with a matching `firstName` and `lastName`.
- A subset of these users (around 100) have data in both "data_xxxx" tables.
- For the 2013 data, the `userName` is an 8 character string.  For the 2016 data, the `userName` is their current email address (which is not necessarily the same one used in 2013).

I can get all the users who have data for 2016 w/a query like this:

```
SELECT firstName,lastName,userName 
FROM users 
WHERE created > '2016-01-01' 
AND userName IN(SELECT uid FROM data_2016)`
```

But what I want now is a query that would give me the list of users, by `userName`, that have 2013 data.  However, as I said, the `userName` (or `uid`) does not match, however the `firstName` and `lastName` values should.

I need something like this, in pseudo-code:

```
SELECT userName 
FROM users 
WHERE created < '2014-01-01' 
and firstName,lastName IN (
    SELECT firstName,lastName 
    FROM users 
    WHERE created > '2016-01-01' 
    AND userName IN(SELECT uid FROM data_2016))
```

I'm sure a union or join is the answer, but I can't figure it out.

Any tips?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is some example data from `users` table:

```
    +------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
    | userName               | firstName | lastName | email                  | created             |
    +------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
    | rwhite                 | ROBERT    | WHITE    | xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com   | 2013-08-05 13:13:23 | 
    | rwhite@company.com     | Robert    | White    | rwhite@company.com     | 2016-10-23 20:26:52 | 
    +------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

Example of above user's 2013 data:

```
    +--------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
    | uid    | created             | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 |
    +--------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
    | rwhite | 2013-08-05 13:24:24 | 38 | 31 |  7 | 22 | 46 |
    +--------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Example of above users's 2016 data:

```
    +--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
    | uid                | created             | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 |
    +--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
    | rwhite@company.com | 2016-10-24 12:37:29 | 38 | 48 | 59 | 71 | 17 |
    +--------------------+---------------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**EDIT2**

I forgot that I had a 4th table that has extra data for certain customers:

```
Create Table users_custA (
  userName VARCHAR,
  id_num VARCHAR,
  etc.
)
```

and example of the same user in this table:

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| userName           | id_num    |
+--------------------+-----------+
| rwhite             | N00123450 | 
| rwhite@company.com | N00123450 | 
+--------------------+-----------+
```

This `id_num` is guaranteed to be unique to a given person (i.e., R White is a single person with two entries in `users_custA` table).

The question remains the same: how can I construct a query that generates a list of userNames that have data in both data_xxxx tables?

Comment: Do your data_* tables have firstName and lastName fields?

Comment: Show us some sample will be more helpful.

Comment: data_* tables only have these fields: uid,d1..dN,created

Comment: added some example data

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unreliable, generally, to expect names to be unique and consistent across time, but if you're sure that it's the case in your data, then you could tweak your query like this (assume you have case-insensitive collation):

```
SELECT userName 
FROM users As u2013
WHERE created >= '2013-01-01' 
AND created < '2014-01-01'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM users As u2016
    WHERE created >= '2016-01-01' 
    AND created < '2017-01-01'
    AND u2016.FirstName = u2013.FirstName
    AND u2016.LastName = u2013.LastName
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_2016 WHERE data_2016.uid = u2016.userName));
```

You would use `WHERE EXISTS` rather than `WHERE ... IN` because [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) doesn't support `WHERE (col1, col2) IN ...`, it only supports it for a single column [or so I understand.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298139/is-where-in-with-multiple-columns-defined-in-standard-sql)

**EDIT**

You can integrate your `users_custA` table in this way to get a more certain match:

```
Select *
  From users_custA 
  Where id_num In (
    SELECT id_num
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT id_num 
          FROM users As u
          JOIN users_custA As a On u.userName = a.userName
          WHERE created >= '2013-01-01' 
          AND created < '2014-01-01'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT id_num
          FROM users As u
          JOIN users_custA As a On u.userName = a.userName
          WHERE created >= '2016-01-01'
          AND created < '2017-01-01') As union_subquery
      GROUP BY id_num
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 2);
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  will give it a try.  before I do so, though, I must mention - I forgot I had 4th table that has a unique ID for each user.  will explain more in another edit.  i agree that relying on names is BAD.

Comment: @atreyu In your question you say that the `users_custA` table has "extra data for *some* customers". If it doesn't have *all* customers in it then I don't think it would be helpful in answering your query.

Comment: good point.  fortunately, i can guarantee that, while the `users_custA` table does not have extra data for every user in the `users` table, it does have extra data for every user in the `data_xxxx` tables, which is all that matters to me, for this query.

Comment: @atreyu I added an alternate version that can use the new table you mentioned.